# Charles Proxy vs Chrome Inspect Element

Tags: google-chrome, charles-proxy

I am new to *Charles Proxy*. As far as I have read, it gives me ability to see all the calls happening from within my application.

Is there any difference between what we can do using *Charles Proxy* and Chrome -> Inspect Element -> Network ?

My requirement is as follows:

I would like to see all the calls (specifically API calls) being made by the application I am browsing and that is to any levels.

Is this possible by any of them?

I am seeing one level API call but not any further (i.e. not multi-level).

Is this because none of the captures server to server API calls, which I feel should be.

Please let me know if any further information is needed to get the whole context.

Answer (score 0):

After a bit more exploring found answer to the question

"I would like to see all the calls (specifically API calls) being made by the application I am browsing and that is to any levels."

This is possible through Charles Proxy but we need to have the application running in local. This is obvious server to server API calls will not be exposed so as a developer if he/she wants to get the any-level API calls being made by the application that he/she is trying to explore, the solution will be to setup the application locally and configure Charles Proxy.

Please share if anyone wants to share any other thought.